# creating an expandable app bar with datepicker in vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to create an expandable app bar in Vuetify, which shows a datepicker within the app bar when the app bar is expanded.

When the app bar is expanded, the datepicker is shown as an overlay instead of expanding the app bar. How do I make the app bar expand to contain the datepicker instead of showing the datepicker on top of the app bar.

I have created a codepen as an example: https://codepen.io/thomasabcd/pen/eYmOoVQ

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <div>
      <v-app-bar dark>

        <v-toolbar-title>Page title</v-toolbar-title>

        <v-spacer></v-spacer>

        <v-btn icon @click="extended=!extended">
          <v-icon>mdi-calendar</v-icon>
        </v-btn>

        <template v-slot:extension v-if="extended">
          <v-date-picker full-width />
        </template>
      </v-app-bar>
    </div>
  </v-app>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data(){
    return{
      extended: false
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: The doc here suggests to use `v-content` for dynamically sizing. https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/application#default-application-markup

Comment: I'll try to come up with a working code. Meanwhile, please experiment with `v-content`

Answer (score 0):

Use the `extension-height` prop of the app-bar..

```
    <v-app-bar dark extension-height="100%">
          <v-toolbar-title>Page title</v-toolbar-title>
          <v-spacer></v-spacer>
          <v-btn icon @click="extended=!extended">
              <v-icon>mdi-calendar</v-icon>
          </v-btn>
          <template v-slot:extension v-if="extended">
              <v-date-picker full-width dark />
          </template>
    </v-app-bar>
```

https://codeply.com/p/tJ3HM4HRZg

Comment: for some reason it doesn't work with the latest version of Vuetify. But it does work with Vuetify 2.0.4, which is the version in your example. Here is the exact same code with Vuetify 2.0.4:https://codepen.io/thomasabcd/pen/dyPbxJP and with the latest version (2.1.12): https://codepen.io/thomasabcd/pen/jOENgpx